# Accessing nested FormBuilder Angular6

Tags: angular, formbuilder, angular-reactive-forms

i have a simple reactive form

```
this.orderForm = this._formBuilder.group({
    metadataFormGroup: this._formBuilder.group({
      data1: ['', [Validators.pattern(this.nserRegex)]],
      data2: ['', [Validators.pattern(this.crqRegex)]]
    }),

    infoFormGroup: this._formBuilder.group({
      data3: ['', [Validators.pattern(this.blcRegex)]],
      data4: new FormControl([])
    })
  });
```

I am trying to access the

```
this.orderForm['metadataFormGroup'].controls['data1'].setValue('11111111')
```

But it is giving erro that `ERROR TypeError: "this.orderForm.metadataFormGroup is undefined"`

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this by using get method

```js
this.orderForm.get('metadataFormGroup').get('data1').setValue('11111111');
```

The line above can be simplfy by using get property

```js
get  metadataFormGroup(){
  return this.orderForm.get('metadataFormGroup');
}
```

Then you can set the value like this

```js
this.metadataFormGroup.get('data1').setValue('11111111');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the nested group via `controls` so `this.orderForm.controls['metadataFormGroup']...`. However, a bit cleaner solution (in my opinion) is:

```ts
this.orderForm.get('metadataFormGroup').get('data1').setValue('...');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value of metadataFormGroup by

```
this.orderForm.setValue({
  ...this.orderForm.value,
  metadataFormGroup: {
    data1,
    data2
  }
});
```

You can get value of metadataFormGroup by

```
this.orderForm.value.metadataFormGroup
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setValue` to update it

> The setValue() method to set a new value for an individual control.
>   The setValue() method strictly adheres to the structure of the form
>   group and replaces the entire value for the control.

```
 this.orderForm.get('metadataFormGroup').get('data1').setValue('Testing');
```

Here  `get` method Retrieves a child control given the control's name or path.

**[Here is the working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rpehhb)**